# MFC + Threads - Window stucking / moving very slow

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, mfc

Yesterday I have created a few classes, which should update tabs (add, remove) dynamically from a MFC Window.

### A short overview:

My `MainWindow` has a object of `CTabCtrl`.
My `MainWindow` has a object of `Watcher*`.
This `CTabCtrl` is passed to a the object `Watcher*` in `OnInitDialog` and the Thread is being started.

The class `Watcher`

- inherits from a Thread class and **is a Thread**
- has a pointer to my **CTabCtrl** of **MainWindow**
- has a std::map(DWORD_PTR, std::auto_ptr[**DetailsView**])
- looks for Windows with a special name, and if found, it creates a new object of **DetailsView** and adds it as new tab

  #### @1
- validiates - **IsWindow(HWND)** - on each run of the loop, that all found Windows, for which the tab has been created, are still valid

#### @1

```
DetailsView *dv = new DetailsView(hwndFoundWindow);
dv->Create(DetailsView::IDD, m_MyOwner);
//std::map<DWORD_PTR, std::auto_ptr<DetailsView> >::insert(std::make_pair(ID, dv));
int iTabCount = (CTabCtrl*).GetItemCount();
LONG lInsertedItem = (CTabCtrl*).InsertItem(TCIF_TEXT, iTabCount + 1, uText(""), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The class `DetailsView` inherits from **CDialogEx**.

The class `DetailsView` has a object of `UpdateDetails*`.

The class `UpdateDetails`

- inherits from a Thread class and **is a  Thread**.
- has a std::map(EnumDetails, CWnd*) which stores - in the current case - all **CEdit**-boxes of **DetailsView**
- validiates - **IsWindow(HWND)** - also and simply uses the  second of the std::map(CWnd*) second->SetWindowTextW

### My problem:

- It is very slow, it moves slowly when dragging (no "soft" dragging) and changes the tabs also very slowly.

*Please leave a comment if you need more information regarding this issue.*

Comment: Building cross-thread window hierarchies is not recommended. When you create a `DetailsView` from your `Watcher` thread, you're adding it to a `CTabCtrl` that is owned by a different thread. You should build your entire GUI on a single thread, and have the `Watcher` thread report events to the GUI thread (through messages or another synchronization mechanism).

Comment: @IInspectable I see, thank you. I will re-write it to be like this.